# Clicar no botão e abrir outra Activity

Tags: android, android-activity

Estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo em JAVA , e vai ter 2 opções para a pessoa escolher, quero que quando ela aperte em 1 dos 2 botoes abra uma nova Activity no aplicativo, Alguém pode por favor me dizer qual o código para isso ?
Estou utilizando o Android Studio.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Para isso você pode utilizar o método startActivity ( [Documentação](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startActivity(android.content.Intent)) )

Este método solicita como parâmetro um [Intent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html)

Neste deve se informar um [Context](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html) (no caso sua Activity) e a `class` da Activity que deseja abrir:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SegundaActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

**ADICIONAR O CLICK EM UM BOTÃO ATRAVÉS DO XML:**

No Seu `xml` no primeiro elemento adicione a seguinte linha:

```
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
```

Com isto você poderá adicionar qual é a classe de contexto deste xml:

```
 tools:context="seu.pacote.app.SuaActivity"
```

Após, vamos informar no botão qual o método ele irá chamar:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button"
<!-- ira chamar o metodo proximaTela -->
    android:onClick="proximaTela"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="-2dp" />
```

No Java adicione o método um método público `void` e que receba uma View como parâmetro:

```
public class SuaTela extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.sua_tela);
    }

    public void proximaTela(View view){

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, SegundaActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado.

Comment: Só lembrando que não pode esquecer de declarar a nova Activity no AndroidManifest.xml
<activity android:name=".SuaNovaActivity" />

Comment: Muito obrigado Thiago!!!