# Chamando outra tela no android

Tags: android, android-activity

```
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() { }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(
            LayoutInflater inflater, 
            ViewGroup container,
            Bundle saveInstanceState) {

        View rootView = 
                inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

        Button btnNumberGuessGame = 
                rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnNumberGuessGame);

        btnNumberGuessGame.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = 
                        new Intent(getActivity(), NumberGuessGame.class);
                getActivity().startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Não está chamando outra tela, teoricamente o código está "certo".

Comment: Eu não vejo código nenhum na pergunta. Por favor, edite a pergunta para incluir código.

Comment: Adicionei o código aí, ele não chama a segunda tela

Comment: Veja isto penso que seja isso [POST](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/190405/clicar-no-bot%C3%A3o-e-abrir-outra-activity)

Comment: Aparece algum erro no console?

Comment: A Activity NumberGuessGame foi declarada no *AndroidManifest.xml*?